# Module not found: Can't resolve 'next-mdx-import-source-file'

Tags: next.js, mdxjs

I am trying to get `@next/mdx` running with the new app directory. I followed the setup in the Readme of the package but i get the following error message when I try to render an mdx page. I can not find any information on this package what so ever.

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'next-mdx-import-source-file'
  1 | import { Fragment as _Fragment, jsx as _jsx, jsxs as _jsxs } from "react/jsx-runtime";
> 2 | import { useMDXComponents as _provideComponents } from "next-mdx-import-source-file";
  3 | function _createMdxContent(props) {
  4 |     const _components = Object.assign({
  5 |         h1: "h1",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs if the file `mdx-components.js` is not present in the project root directory.

This dependency is not an actual package but rather some next magic which actually imports the `mdx-components.js` file. In my case I missed out on on the plural.

Answer (score 3):

The `vercel/next.js` [beta documentation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/guides/mdx) itself indicates that the `mdx-components.jsx` file must be in the root of the application (not inside `app`). Here is an [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/app-dir-mdx).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else dealing with this, I fixed it by overriding the alias value and creating the file mentioned above in the root of the project:

```
config.resolve.alias['next-mdx-import-source-file'] = 'private-next-root-dir/mdx-components';
```